# Set theory - is this a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose that $A,B$ are sets. Is
$$
\{ y \in B | \exists x \in A: y \in x \}
$$
a set? I tried to find a formal proof (replacement? comprehension?) or to show that it doesn't exist (regularity?), but I'm not really familiar with this stuff. Of course it must have to do something with ur-elements or power sets, but I'm to confused now to figure out what is going on.

In the same spirit: If $A$ is a set, is it meaningful to ask whether there exists a set $\Omega$ such that $A=\mathbb{P}(\Omega)$?

[edit]: Hm, what about:If $A$ is a set, is it meaningful to ask whether there exists a set $\Omega$ such that $A\subseteq\mathbb{P}(\Omega)$?

Comment: Is a subset of $B$...

Comment: As for your second question: yes it is meaningful to ask but it might not exist

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are sets, rewriting the condition as $\{ y : y \in B \land \exists x (x \in A \land y \in x) \}$, you must apply *Axiom schema of Separation* and you will get it.

Comment: How does this give a formula $\phi$ which I can use in the Axiom of Separation? Your formula contains $A,B$? Or am I so confused?

Comment: It is a formula $\phi(y)$ with a free variable: so it is ok. And the *Axiom* needs that you "separate" your new set from an existing one, in order to license you to assert that the condition gives you a set, and this is the $y \in B$ part.

Comment: Also note that separation and comprehension are two different names for the same thing in this setting.

Comment: Thank you very much! But your formula contains three variables, it is $\phi(y,A,B)$ - isn't that a Problem? Sorry if this is stupid.

Comment: You can have plenty of variables. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification

Comment: Thank @Apostolos - the key issues are two : *(i)* the formula used for express the condition to bu used to "separate" must be a wff (i.e. a formula stisfying the syntactical rules of the language: for "standard" $ZFC$ we assume first-order); *(ii)* we must use the condition to "separate" the new set from an (already proved to be) existing set.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I still can't figure out the formula which I can plugin the axiom as stated at Wikipedia. The article says that the other variable (here A) must not be free in $\phi$. Thank you all, I will try harder.

Comment: There are no reason to think that "your" $A$ is "the same" $A$ of Wiki... As @Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla said, you are "separating"a new set (call it $X$) from an existing set $B$ (and so it will be a subset of $B$); using *Separation*, your $B$ will be the $A$ of Wiki. In separating it, you will impose on the elements of $B$ (in order to be eligible to belong to $X$) a condition $\phi$; this conditions says that they must (in addition to be elements of $B$) be elements of elements (the $x$) of a third set that you called $A$ (again, it is not the $A$ of Wiki).

Comment: This might be a bit late but I still don't understand what is the problem. The axiom in wikipedia states that for all $A$ and $B$ the set that you write down exists.

Answer (score 0):

About the second question. It is *meaningful* to ask. The answer is obviously false in general.